# Как вывести определенное число элементов массива VUE JS

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, django-rest-framework

Собственно вопрос в шапке, перелазил везде, нигде не пишут

Comment: Не отвечают наверное от того, что вопрос расплывчатый до невозможности. В каком виде данные представлены, что за массив, где хранится, как передаётся. Самый простой вариант если массив уже сохранен в js - передайте срез массива (arr.slice вроде как) в props компонента.

Comment: все данные с API, всё дефолтно
<div id="posts" v-for="(post, slug) in posts">
Нужно чтобы вывело первых 5 постов, например, по дате публикации. В джанго это было просто, здесь я не понимаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых данная запись `<div id="posts" v-for="(post, slug) in posts">` невозможна, директива `v-for` работает аналогично функции `Array.prototype.forEach`, первым параметром принимает `currentValue`, вторым `index` (`array` не принимает), а не `slug`, но это при работе с массивом, если итерировать объект - там все иначе. Если нужно вывести 5 первых элементов - используйте `Array.prototype.slice`:

```
<div id="posts" v-for="post in posts.slice(0, 5)">
```

Если нужно по дате публикации, то сортируйте массив:

```
data() {
    return {
        posts: []
    };
},

mounted() {
    makeApiCall().then((posts) => {
        this.$data.posts = posts.sort((a, b) => {
            return new Date(b.publish_date) - new Date(a.publish_date);
        }).slice(0, 5);
    });
}
```

А вообще для таких целей создавайте API эндпоинт, который будет возвращать первые 5 постов по дате публикации, чтобы уменьшить нагрузку на фронт

Comment: у меня бэк django rest api, т.е. легче создать отдельную ссылку по первым пяти статьям ?

Comment: ну представьте, что у Вас эндпоинт `GET /api/posts` возвращает ~1k постов, то фронту придется сортировать 1k по дате, всю "такую" логику выносите на бек

Comment: понял, спасибо вам!